# Can you solve this compiler problem with the following code

Tags: java

I keep getting an unexpected type error on this code but I'm not too sure where. Could you please spot where I'm going wrong?

```
  public String rev(String word, int start, int end){

    String input = word;

    while(start < end){

        char hold = input.charAt(start);           
        input.charAt(start) = input.charAt(end);                       
        input.charAt(end) = hold;
        start++;
        end--;
    }
    return input;

}
```

Comment: `charAt()`  returns a `char`. You can't assign to it. Java strings are immutable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't assign to `input.charAt(start)` or `input.charAt(end)`. Convert the `String` to a `char[]`, do the work on that, and then convert it back at the end.

```
char[] chars = input.toCharArray();

// your loop here . . .

return new String(chars);
```

The reason you can't assign to the return value of the `charAt` method is that it is not what is called an lvalue. This is a term, along with rvalue, that dates back to the C programming language, although 'lvalues' and 'rvalues' are called 'variables' and 'values' in the Java specification. The idea is that only certain things can appear on the left hand side (LHS) of an assignment operator. In Java, an lvalue is either a local variable, a field, a static (class) variable, an array element -- it has to be something you can assign a value to. The `charAt` method returns an actual value, not a reference to an element of the array backing the string, so it is an rvalue, and cannot appear on the LHS of an assignment.

Additionally, strings in Java are immutable, so even if the syntax were not wrong, you still could not modify the string directly.

Comment: They aren't called "lvalues" and "rvalues" in Java: the spec refers to them as "variables" and "values". As far as I understand it, the terms are directly analogous to the C ones; but I it's helpful to use the names for specific to the language

Comment: @AndyTurner Thanks. I added a mention of those terms.